# Ancestry gem in Rails and Mutli Nesting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ancestry

I am using the ancestry gem in rails to nest some comments, and what I wanted was for you to be able to get all comments and then have them all nested. How ever I get the following when I put: `@comments = post.comments.arrange_serializable` into my comments controller index action and get the following result:

```
{
   "comments":[
      {
         "id":3,
         "comment":"284723nbrkdgfiy2r84ygwbdjhfg8426trgfewuhjf",
         "author":"asdasdasdas",
         "post_id":268,
         "ancestry":null,
         "created_at":"2014-06-17T19:23:04.667Z",
         "updated_at":"2014-06-17T19:23:04.667Z",
         "children":[
            {
               "id":4,
               "comment":"284723nbrkdgfiy2r84ygwbdjhfg8426trgfewuhjf",
               "author":"asdasdasdas",
               "post_id":268,
               "ancestry":"3",
               "created_at":"2014-06-17T19:24:02.408Z",
               "updated_at":"2014-06-17T19:24:02.408Z",
               "children":[

               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":5,
         "comment":"97ryhewfkhbdasifyt834rygewbfj,dhsg834",
         "author":"asdasdasd",
         "post_id":268,
         "ancestry":"4",
         "created_at":"2014-06-17T20:30:04.887Z",
         "updated_at":"2014-06-17T20:38:16.060Z",
         "children":[

         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

It's very apparent that comment with `id: 5` is suppose to be in the array of `children` which sits in comment `id: 4` which **IS** nested under comment with `id: 3`.

Can some one one tell me why `arrange_serializable` does not "multi nest" comments? or if there is another function to do this with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Structure**

Your `arrange_serializable` seems to be working - I think the problem is with how you're nesting the comments

We found out (took us ages) that if you want to use "nested" categories, you need to use a `slash` like this:

[image]

So if you're trying to "deep nest", you need to ensure you're including the whole route to the root object. Common logic would suggest "inheriting" from nested objects would also allow them to be nested - not so.

--

**Fix**

For your `id` `5`, you should make the `ancestry` column this value:

```
$ rails c
$ comment = Comment.find 5
$ comment.update(ancestry: "3/4")
```

--

**Partial**

If you wanted to show a nested array of categories in your view, we use the following code:

[image]

```
#app/views/elements/_category.html.erb
<!-- Categories -->
<ol class="categories">
    <% collection.arrange.each do |category, sub_item| %>
        <li>
            <!-- Category -->
            <%= category.title %>

            <!-- Children -->
            <% if category.has_children? %>
                <%= render partial: "category", locals: { collection: category.children } %>
            <% end %>

        </li>
    <% end %>
</ol>


#app/views/application/index.html.erb
<%= render partial: "category", locals: { collection: Category.all } %>
```