# how display certain branch of blog?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ancestry

please help solve the problem. i use gem 'ancestry'. i made simply blog. 
messages_helper.rb:

```
module MessagesHelper
  def nested_messages(messages)
    messages.map do |message, sub_messages|
      render(message) + content_tag(:div, nested_messages(sub_messages), :class => "nested_messages")
    end.join.html_safe
  end  
end
```

index.html.erb:

```
<%= nested_messages @messages.arrange(:order => :created_at) %>
<br>
<%= render 'form' %>
```

schema:

```
create_table "messages", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.text     "content"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.string   "ancestry"
end
```

in result i output to index.html.erb tree of messages with related messages. but i need output only certain message with related messages. e.g. for message with id=3

ps:
for made blog i use this tutorial: 
http://railscasts.com/episodes/262-trees-with-ancestry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, [I've written about this before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24273419/ancestry-gem-in-rails-and-mutli-nesting); there are certain things which you've got to fix with the Railscast recommendations:

> 1. Put it in a partial, not helper (it gives greater autonomy)
> 2. You need to make sure your structure is as versatile as you need

--

Here's how I'd do what you're trying to achieve:

```
#app/controllers/messages_controller.rb
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @messages = Message.all #-> could filter this to only retrieve id=3
      #@messages = Message.find "3" #-> like this
   end
end

#app/views/messages/index.html.erb
<% render @messages.arrange(order: :created_at) %>

#app/views/messages/_message.html.erb
# ... single message output code ... #
<%= render message.children if message.has_children? && message.id == "3" %>
```

You could then extrapolate the conditional functionality into a helper. If you describe your functionality more specifically, I'll be able to make a helper to define it.